# USB Device driver failed to send descriptor / USB enumeraion

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-drive, stm32f4

I am writing a usb driver from scratch on STM32F4 to work as a msc deivce. However it always failed at enumeration process. Here is a sequence of events happened when I tested it:

1. On start, it received rxqlvl interrupt then read the setup packet from host to get descriptor.
2. It then set the xfersize(=18) and pktcnt(=1) and epena=1 and cnak=1 in the corresponding register of endpoint0(IN).
3. In the "empty tx fifo" interrupt callback it wrote the descriptor content(18 bytes) to data fifo0.
4. It got "xfercomplete" in-endpoint interrupt.
5. It received the second setup packet from host to set address, then set the address in the device config register and sent a zero length packet back to host.

After all aboves steps, the driver got RESET and then received the setup packet again as in step 1 from host asking for device descritpor (wValue=0x100), and then ran through step 1-5 again and again... What I am expecting here is that after step5 host should instead ask for config descriptor (wValue=0x200) instead of resetting the device, right?

I used usbmon to capture the log of host as below:

```
ffff93b39f300fc0 3605221398 S Ci:1:000:0 s 80 06 0100 0000 0040 64 <
ffff93b39f300fc0 3610458920 C Ci:1:000:0 -2 64 = 12010002 00000040 c0168b08 00010102 03010000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

It seems like host it getting error (-2). The host should have already received the descriptor but something else went wrong. What could I do to fix/debug this problem?

Comment: _In the "empty tx fifo" interrupt callback it wrote the descriptor content(18 bytes) to data fifo0._ How exactly? I am not familiar with the tool you are using (does this mean host is linux?) but it appears to indicate it received 64 byte of data instead of 18? There's also no mention of the subsequent set address setum packet you've said you received, which adds to my confusion. I usually recommend using a hardware protocol analyzer for this kind of work as software monitors on host may be confusing; some oscilloscopes and LA have decoders for USB.